# Twitter bootstrap modals not loading and the screen just turns slightly darker

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have six modals but only the first two are working - when I click on the link for the other four, nothing happens and the screen just turns slightly darker.
Here's my code (#portfolioModal2 works fine but #portfolioModal3 doesn't):

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 portfolio-item">
<div class="interests">
  <a href="#portfolioModal2" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
    <img src="/assets/work1.png" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 portfolio-item">
<div class="interests">
  <a href="#portfolioModal3" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
    <img src="/assets/travelingcover1.png" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

---

```
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <%= render 'work' %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <%= render 'traveling' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It sounds like the tabindex is putting the modal behind the grey-out overlay.  Change the tab index and see what happens.

Comment: Hi there! I tried changing the tab index but it's still not working - and it's weird because the code is identical to the one's that are working (and it used to work some days ago)

Comment: You may also need to set zindex to bring the div above the grey-out.